# ti not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-android

I am developing Android applications using appcelerator. I am trying to build it through command using

```
titanium build -p android -b
```

argument.But it show 'ti'not recognized as internal or external command error.

The app run fine on emulator.I need to build it through command or on device.But my device also not accessing on Appcelerator.

Please help me to troubleshoot ti issue on command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

are you using it in Windows OS? You probably did not configure the development environment properly.

You should follow this guide: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installation_and_Configuration

and in particular the Software Locations and Environment Variables:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables